# static Hashtable<Leader, ArrayList<Integer>> assignedLeader=new Hashtable<Leader, ArrayList<Integer>>(20);

Tags: arraylist, hashtable

I need to add elements to a hashtable and my hashtable needs to have an array list. But I am not able to find a way to add elements in the table properly. Please help me out.

```
static Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> assignedLeader =
    new Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>(20);
```

Comment: Can we see what code you've tried so far?

Comment: I tried many but all gave errors so no use writing bad code here

Comment: use HashMap instead of Hashtable if you are planning to use this code in a single threaded application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just only for your reference .

```
static Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> assignedLeader =
            new Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>(20);

    ArrayList<Integer> al=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    al.add(1);
    al.add(2);
    al.add(3);

    assignedLeader.put(1, al);
```